# can I buy ddr3 ram for my laptop or I have to buy ddr2?

Tags: laptop, memory, hp-pavilion, ddr3, ddr2

My laptop is **Hp pavilion dv5 1041et**

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&lc=en&product=3793488

It has 4GB RAM (but my current windows is x86 so it does not matter).
However I decided to buy new harddrive and install there x64 windows.

Can I buy for it DDR3 modules or I should buy DDR2 modules? (I am planning to buy 2x4GB modules). Because if it's DDR2 only then I think I have no reason to increase memory...

Comment: If your system has DDR2 then DDR3 will not fit in the same place. The sticks of memory are keyed differently and you cannot fit one in place of the other.

Comment: You may need special LPDIMM's which are physically smaller. Check your documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DDR3 does not fit in this model.** It will not physically fit. It will not work electrically. It will not work in your system.

Howeever,
If you are already installing x64 bit version you can add more memory.

I would suggest 2x 4096 MB DDR2
because your system support max 8GiB RAM

This would be the easiest way to upgrade.

[Product specifications](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01539289&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=3793488#N45)

Comment: Well the problem is that it costs more at my place and also is there a reason to upgrade DDR2? Performance won't be better because it's rather old memory. The same as there is no reason to upgrade DDR.

Comment: Usually you upgrade memory to get more of it, so you avoid running out of memory when running programs which can slow down the whole computer. Making the memory itself faster usually isn't that important.  So upgrading your memory *might* help. But why upgrade at all? Why not just stay on x86 with 4GB of ram? The answer may depend on what problem you are trying to solve.